# Displaying Midnight Commander screen in JTextPane

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I've tried to connect by SSH to a server and get an output for my commands. Everything works fine if I put out into `System.out`. Else if I want to put it into `JTextPane`, it puts it, but MC is unreadable.

This is my code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();

String command = "";
String commandR = "";
host = null;

if (arg.length > 1) {
    host = arg[0];
    command = arg[2];
    commandR = arg[3];
}

String user = host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
host = host.substring(host.indexOf('@') + 1);
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);

session.setPassword(arg[1]);
if (!session.isConnected()) {
    session.connect();
}

Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");

String ans = " ";
InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
//channel.setInputStream(System.in);
if (!channel.isConnected()) {
    channel.connect(10 * 1000);
}
boolean logon = false;
boolean started = false;
boolean brtuser = false;
boolean log = false;
byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];

JFrame j = new JFrame();
JTextPane jj = new JTextPane();
jj.setContentType("text/html");
StyledDocument  doc = (StyledDocument )jj.getDocument();
jj.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 600));
j.setDefaultCloseOperation(2);
j.add(new JScrollPane(jj));
j.pack();
j.setVisible(true);
while (!started) {

    while (in.available() > 0) {
        int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
        if (i < 0) {
            break;
        }

        // jj.append();

        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), new String(tmp, 0, i), null);
        ans += new String(tmp, 0, i);
        System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
```

Then I write `pwd` and `mc` - `pwd` I get fine, but `mc` is such as

```
39m[49m                                                                              
    [37m[40m                                                                                [23;3H[22;1H[39m[49mGNU Midnight Commander 4.6.0                                                    
      [1;1H[30m[46m  Left     File     Command     Options     Right                               
    [37m[44m+[0m[37m[44m<[37m[44m-[0m[37m[44m~[37m[44m---------------------------------[0m[37m[44mv>[37m[44m++[0m[30m[47m<[37m[44m-[0m[30m[47m~[37m[44m---------------------------------[0m[30m[47mv>[37m[44m+
    |[0m[1m[33m[44m       Name      [0m[37m[44m|[0m[1m[33m[44m Size  [0m[37m[44m|[0m[1m[33m[44m   MTime    [0m[37m[44m||[0m[1m[33m[44m       Name      [0m[37m[44m|[0m[1m[33m[44m Size  [0m[37m[44m|[0m[1m[33m[44m   MTime    [0m[37m[44m|
    |[0m[1m[37m[44m/..              [0m[37m[44m|[0m[1m[37m[44mUP--DIR[0m[37m[44m|[0m[1m[37m[44m            [0m[37m[44m||[0m[30m[46m/..              [30m[46m|[0m[30m[46mUP--DIR[30m[46m|[0m[30m[46m            [37m[44m|
    |[0m[1m[37m[44m/.mc             [0m[37m[44m|[0m[1m[37m[44m   1024[0m[37m[44m|[0m[1m[37m[44mJan 29 11:35[0m[37m[44m||[0m[1m[37m[44m/.mc
```

Please help me to get it viewable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "garbage" that you see in the `JTextPane` are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). These define colors and other formatting. They used by Midnight Commander (and other applications) to render a GUI-like interface on a text console.

The ANSI escape codes are understood by Terminal/SSH clients like PuTTY. Even by console windows in various OSes (e.g. Windows). That's probably, why it looks good when you print the output to `System.out`.

But they are not understood by `JTextPane`, it displays them as they are.

See [ANSI colors in Java  Swing text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6899282/850848) for "ANSI colored `JTextPane` subclass".