# jQuery terminal - Reading shell response in Java as string shows weird characters in jQuery terminal

Tags: java, jsch, jquery-terminal

I'm currently using a piped input/output stream principe to read from and write to a shell channel using JSCH.

Problem: I'm getting weird characters in my jQuery terminal when I transport the response of the shell to jQuery terminal.

Weird characters (jQuery terminal):
[image]

I tried reading the piped input stream in different ways to solve the problem:

Try 1:

```
private synchronized String readResponse() throws IOException {
    byte[] array = new byte[pin.available()];
    pin.read(array);
    return new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

Try 2:

```
private synchronized String readResponse() throws IOException {
        final StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        while(pin.available() > 0) {
            s.append((char) pin.read());
        }
        return s.toString();
    }
```

Sadly this problem still persist. Can anyone help me?

**Update:**
I just found out that, when I print the same string in my Java output console, it works.

Java's System.out:
[image]

**Update 2:**
I've imported the unix_formatting.js file and it's almost fixed. The thing with this file is that it has limited support for unix escape codes. Link to js: https://unpkg.com/jquery.terminal@1.23.2/js/unix_formatting.js

Currently looks like this:
[image]

How can I fix this problem in jQuery terminal?

Comment: Because jQuery Terminal supports limited number of ANSI escapes codes, you can just include unix_formatting.js file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl you can reopen because issue is in front-end and duplicate is for UI text field not related to html.

Comment: I closed this issue because the possible duplicated thread led me to jQuery's terminal unix_formatting.js. I imported the file and it's kind of fixed. But it's not completely fixed because the unix_formatting.js supports a limited amount of ANSI escape codes.

Comment: Reposting the link: See [Displaying Midnight Commander screen in JTextPane](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28211577/850848).

Comment: I've updated the OP.

Comment: With unix_formatting you can only have static output, if you want real tty you can try xterm.js see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that by default jQuery Terminal don't support ANSI escape codes but you can enable basic support by including unix_formatting.js file, the file is created using UMD so you can import it and have it in Webpack or Rollup bundle or include it using script tag:

Simplest is using unpkg.com:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery.terminal/js/unix_formatting.js"></script>
```

you can also use same CDN as for main files (jsDeliver or cdnJS)

I think that `cdn.rawgit.com` will work until October 2019 so it's better to not use that one.

But, the one thing that jQuery Terminal can't do so is that you will never be able to display interactive shell command in Terminal in browser. The library was created for writing your own commands in JavaScript with basic support for shell command in unix_formatting file.

If you want to have full unix terminal in browser the better choice will be [xterm.js](https://xtermjs.org/) which is real tty. If you can run the server, which you probably can if you're running java then xterm.js will be much better. You can even run `vi` or `emacs -nw` with it.

Comment: Thanks for your xterm reference. I think that's the solution. However I tried implementing it, but I end up with a weird situation. Whenever I type one key in the terminal, it directly writes it to the server. Here's a gif: https://i.imgur.com/gP82rwX.gif

This is how I've setup my terminal:
https://hastebin.com/udobequheh.html

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never mind, I got everything working like a charm. I ended up with this script: https://hastebin.com/yowigijipe.html

Using xterm is the right solution.